# Unable to use npm package in my gatsby (react) component

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, gatsby

Hello everyone i am trying to use this npm package i found in my gatsby js project https://www.npmjs.com/package/boxrec-client.

I have tried to import the library in my index.js file but seem to be getting this weird FS module error that cant be found. I have already added the package to yarn. below is my code

my imports look like this

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import boxrecClient from '../../node_modules/boxrec-client';
```

i am currently getting this error in my console and blank page in my localhost window.

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                    7:18:28 PM
⠀
This dependency was not found:
⠀
* fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
⠀
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
✖ ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/kevinlopez/Desktop/sample-site/node_modules/request/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/boxrec-client/index.js
 @ ./src/pages/index.js
 @ ./.cache/sync-requires.js
 @ ./.cache/app.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?path=/__webpack_hmr&reload=true&overlay=false ./.cache/app
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

i have also tried to install this fs package but the error consists would someone be able to guide me in the right direction ? Thanks

Comment: First, you almost never want to import from node_modules, import it normally. Second, "fs" is a node-side library, not browser--you'd need to see if boxrec runs in the browser at all if you're trying to use it on the client side (e.g., not during the Gatsby build).

Comment: ahh makes sense. seems to be a backend nodeJS library. Do you know how i would still be able to use it ?

Answer (score 3):

> A BoxRec client which fetches data from the BoxRec boxing website via web scraping in Node.js. Fetches return promise objects which will resolve with the fetched data if successful.

'fs' is a backend Nodejs library (file-system), you cannot use that in the browser.